# Google Cloud Storage Signed URL for Entire Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have user owned objects in a Google Cloud Storage bucket which I'm controlling access to through a webapp backend. Currently, the webapp backend authenticates the user and then generates [signed read URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for the object. This works great, but can result in high volume of URLs being generated in response to a bulk action. The failure rate of these signed URLs is very low, but when enough of them are generated some fail and a timeout or connection reset is noticeable to users.

Is there any way to give this kind of controlled, time limited access to users at the **bucket** level, or in bulk in another way, without creating GCP accounts for users?

Comment: Signed URLs are per bucket object. Why are some of these URLs failing? I have apps that implement Signed URLs. I send the client a URL to my application (a special route). When a request arrives my app then generates the Signed URL and redirects the client. That prevents the need for long-term Signed URLs.

Comment: @JohnHanley suppose I have a 10 page gallery of thumbnails, with 100 items per page. If 10 users page through the entire gallery, that's 10k signed read URLs. If the GCP signed URL auth works 99.99%  of the time, 10% of my users will see a broken image link. I'm looking for an alternative to auth-ing every image fetch.

Comment: 1) Your question lacks the details to provide a good answer. 2) For example, which framework/language are you using? 3) Most frameworks have good caching modules. You can cache Signed URLs and continue to serve them for a period of time. 4) Another item is you say they fail but you do not provide details on the failure. Signed URLs are created from a certificate private key. It is a data signature and not some special backend process. That process does not fail unless you are overloading Cloud Storage - which I seriously doubt. **You have a bug in your application.**

Answer (score 0):

**You are correct, all these the methods require a service account.  After further investigation, there is no way to provide access without a GCP account.**

At the bucket level, there is [uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access), [Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/iam) (IAM) and [Access Control List](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#default) (ACL). If you want to avoid creating GCP accounts for the users, then try Access Control List (ACL).

In this access control you can also determine who the reader, writer and owners will be.  But this access control lets you use grant access to anyone who has external email addresses.  This will save you the time of creating GCP accounts for the users, here are the scope of who can grant access:

[image]

And here it's what each scope covers:

**Google account email address:**

Every user who has a Google account must have a unique email address associated with that account. You can specify a scope by using any email address that is associated with a Google account, such as a gmail.com address.

Cloud Storage remembers email addresses as they are provided in ACLs until the entries are removed or replaced. If a user changes email addresses, you should update ACL entries to reflect these changes.

**Google group email address:**

Every Google group has a unique email address that is associated with the group. For example, the Cloud Storage Announce group has the following email address: `gs-announce@googlegroups.com`. You can find the email address that is associated with a Google group by clicking About on the homepage of every Google group.

Like Google account email addresses, Cloud Storage remembers group email addresses as they are provided in ACLs until the entries are removed. You do not need to worry about updating Google Group email addresses, because Google Group email addresses are permanent and unlikely to change.

**Convenience values for projects:**

Convenience values allow you to grant bulk access to your project's viewers, editors, and owners. Convenience values combine a project role and an associated project number. For example, in project `867489160491`, editors are identified as `editors-867489160491`. You can find your project number on the homepage of the Google Cloud Console.

You should generally avoid using convenience values in production environments, because they require granting basic roles, a practice which is discouraged in production environments.

**G Suite or Cloud Identity:**

G Suite and Cloud Identity customers can associate their email accounts with an Internet domain name. When you do this, each email account takes the form `USERNAME@YOUR_DOMAIN.com`. You can specify a scope by using any Internet domain name that is associated with G Suite or Cloud Identity.

Special identifier for all Google account holders:
This special scope identifier represents anyone who is authenticated with a Google account. The special scope identifier for all Google account holders is allAuthenticatedUsers. Note that while this identifier is a User entity type, when using the Cloud Console it's labeled as a Public entity type.

**Special identifier for all users:**

This special scope identifier represents anyone who is on the Internet, with or without a Google account. The special scope identifier for all users is allUsers. Note that while this identifier is a User entity type, when using the Cloud Console it's labeled as a Public entity type.

You have full control of the access you want the users to have. You can learn about the access and what each does with the following [link 1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#default),    [Link 2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control).

Comment: @Dave: Was the information provided of any use?

Comment: unless I misunderstand, all these methods require GCP accounts per user -- either human user accounts or service accounts.